# Snap library removing (gir1.2-snapd-1, libsnapd-glib1, libsnappy1v5, libsnappy1v5:i386) with dependencies

Tags: dependencies, snap

My system is Ubuntu-Mate 20.04 and i was install via snap some apps.
Now i decide to remove snaps from my system but i have problem with dependencies.
If try to remove `gir1.2-snapd-1` Synaptic inform me that will remove also:

```
apturl
gnome-software
software-properties-gtk
ubuntu-mate-core
ubuntu-mate-desktop
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
update-manager
update-notifier
```

My worries are if remove ubuntu-mate-core & ubuntu-mate-desktop will not crash my system?

Comment: Canonical has intentionally made snaps hard to remove. They came with your OS. If you don't want snaps, try using a different distro, like Pop!_OS. Why do you want to remove snapd?

Answer (score 1):

I will not recommend to remove the applications because:

- removal of `software-properties-gtk` from the system will remove Software & Updates application which is user-friendly for repository and updates management.
- removal of `ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk`, `update-manager` and `update-notifier` will lead to lack of nice looking update/upgrade manager applications.

Without packages in the above list you convert package management of your system to server-like OS with only terminal-based tools like `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `add-apt-repository`, `do-release-upgrade`. So such system loses usability and user-friendless.

Removal of `gnome-software` is good as it is very slow and dumb application.

But removal of `ubuntu-mate-core` and `ubuntu-mate-desktop` will not trash the system. They are meta-packages.

You can end with removal of Snapd itself by `sudo apt-get purge snapd`.

---

Personally I do not like Snaps too, but in [some cases](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000768/66509) they are useful. For example for installing new package versions on old systems like Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. And for installing some proprietary stuff, which is not presented in the repositories (like video-conference apps).

You can simply leave these packages in the system. Such removal will not free large amount of space.

Comment: I remove gir1.2-snapd-1 and all the others (gnome ..). the changes will applied after restart my pc.So if reinstall all the apps again i think will not have a problem. Do you agree my thought is correct ?

Comment: I agree, nothing critical will happen. I have checked this on fresh UM 20.04 LTS VM.

Comment: I remove libsnappy1v5:i386 and some wine apps deleted and reinstall them.

Answer (score 1):

Some risk, depending upon how your system was built. But you can mitigate that risk.

**Advice**: Do not remove the `gir1.2-snapd-1` deb package for three reasons:

1) Leaving it shouldn't do anything harmful. Without snapd installed, this package might generate a few application errors since the introspected functions don't actually exist without snapd installed. If this bothers you, then go right ahead and delete the `gir1.2-snapd-1` deb package.

2) Removing the depending packages will degrade your ability to control the package manager using desktop features:

```
gnome-software
software-properties-gtk
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
update-manager
update-notifier
```

Of course, if you don't use any of those features then go right ahead and delete the `gir1.2-snapd-1` deb package. It's *your* system.

3) Removing the depending `ubuntu-mate-core` and `ubuntu-mate-desktop` may make other desktop packages eligble for autoremoval.

**This is the part that might trash your system**. Read your apt output carefully before agreeing to any *future* removals or autoremovals. This is mostly a risk for folks who build their system up from a minimal .iso or install the desktop environment using apt. If your desktop does vanish, simply apt install those metapackages again.

Folks who installed the desktop directly using a Desktop install .iso are NOT at risk; the desktop packages are individually apt-marked to prevent precisely this kind of mistake.  Go right ahead and delete the `gir1.2-snapd-1` deb package.

Comment: I remove gir1.2-snapd-1 and all the others (gnome ..). the changes will applied after restart my pc.So if reinstall all the apps again i think will not have a problem. Do you agree my thought is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I remove `libsnappy1v5:i386` and some wine apps deleted and reinstall them. 
Now trying remove `libsnappy1v5` apt display:

> `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     audacity-data breeze-icon-theme ca-certificates-java calf-plugins catdoc
>     dvdauthor fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-wine frei0r-plugins fuseiso gimp-data
>     gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 gstreamer1.0-adapter-pulseeffects
>     gstreamer1.0-autogain-pulseeffects gstreamer1.0-convolver-pulseeffects
>     gstreamer1.0-crystalizer-pulseeffects java-common kaccounts-providers
>     kactivities-bin kactivitymanagerd kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data
>     kdeconnect kded5 kdenlive-data keditbookmarks kinit kio kpackagelauncherqml
>     kpackagetool5 kpeople-vcard libaacs0 libaccounts-qt5-1 libamd2 libaom0
>     libaribb24-0 libass9 libbabl-0.1-0 libbasicusageenvironment1 libbdplus0
>     libbluray2 libbs2b0 libc-ares2 libcamd2 libcapi20-3 libccolamd2 libcddb2
>     libcholmod3 libcodec2-0.9 libdc1394-22 libdc1394-25 libdc1394-utils libdca0
>     libde265-0 libdirectfb-1.7-7 libdvbpsi10 libebml4v5 libebur128-1 libenca0
>     libepub0 libfaad2 libflac++6v5 libflite1 libfluidsynth2 libgavl1
>     libgegl-common libgme0 libgroupsock8 libgsm1 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libheif1
>     libhfstospell10 libid3tag0 libinstpatch-1.0-2 libixml10 libjsoncpp1
>     libkaccounts1 libkate1 libkf5activities5 libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5
>     libkf5auth5 libkf5bluezqt-data libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bookmarks-data
>     libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5completion-data
>     libkf5completion5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5 libkf5declarative-data
>     libkf5declarative5 libkf5doctools5 libkf5filemetadata-data
>     libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data
>     libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5iconthemes-bin
>     libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5itemviews-data
>     libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils-data
>     libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiogui5
>     libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5newstuff-data
>     libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifyconfig-data
>     libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data libkf5parts-plugins
>     libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5 libkf5peoplebackend5
>     libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5pty-data
>     libkf5pty5 libkf5pulseaudioqt2 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5
>     libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data
>     libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5su-bin libkf5su-data libkf5su5
>     libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data
>     libkf5xmlgui5 libkworkspace5-5 liblilv-0-0 liblirc-client0 liblivemedia77
>     libmad0 libmatroska6v5 libmetis5 libminizip1 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmlt-data
>     libmng2 libmodplug1 libmovit8 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0
>     libmypaint-1.5-1 libmypaint-common libmysofa1 libnice10 libnode64 libnorm1
>     libodbc1 libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt-modplug1 libopenmpt0
>     libopenshot-audio6 libpgm-5.2-0 libphonon4qt5-4 libphonon4qt5-data
>     libplacebo7 libpoppler-qt5-1 libportaudio2 libportsmf0v5 libpostproc55
>     libprotobuf-lite17 libproxy-tools libqca-qt5-2 libqca-qt5-2-plugins
>     libqt5multimedia5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5quicktemplates2-5
>     libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5webengine-data libre2-5 libresid-builder0c2a
>     librtaudio6 librttr-core0.9.6 librubberband2 libsbc1 libsdl-image1.2
>     libsdl1.2debian libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsidplay2 libsignon-plugins-common1
>     libsignon-qt5-1 libsndio7.0 libsord-0-0 libsoundtouch1 libsox-fmt-alsa
>     libsox-fmt-base libsox3 libspandsp2 libspatialaudio0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1
>     libsrtp2-1 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssh2-1 libstb0 libsuil-0-0 libswresample3
>     libswscale5 libumfpack5 libupnp13 libusageenvironment3 libusrsctp1
>     libvamp-hostsdk3v5 libvidstab1.1 libvkd3d1 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9
>     libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libvoikko1 libvorbisidec1 libwildmidi2
>     libx265-179 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-damage0 libxvidcore4 libzbar0
>     libzita-convolver3 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mda-lv2 media-player-info
>     nodejs nodejs-doc openjdk-11-jre-headless oxygen-icon-theme phantomjs
>     plasma-framework python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-pyxattr
>     python3-zmq qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-kconfig
>     qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols
>     qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-org-kde-newstuff
>     qml-module-org-kde-people qml-module-org-kde-purpose
>     qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
>     qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtquick-controls
>     qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
>     qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets
>     qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2
>     qml-module-qtwebchannel qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts rtmpdump
>     rubberband-ladspa signon-plugin-oauth2 sonnet-plugins sshfs swh-plugins
>     timgm6mb-soundfont vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt
>     vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter
>     vlc-plugin-visualization xsane-common youtube-dl zam-plugins
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
>   The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     audacity browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash celluloid dvgrab ffmpeg
>     ffmpegthumbnailer frostwire gimp gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
>     kdenlive libasound2-plugins-extra libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra58
>     libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libchromaprint1 libfaudio0
>     libffmpegthumbnailer4v5 libgegl-0.4-0 libgimp2.0 libkf5filemetadata-bin
>     libkf5notifyconfig5 libmlt++3 libmlt6 libmpv1 libopenshot16 libqt5webengine5
>     libqt5webenginecore5 libquicktime2 libsnappy1v5 libwine melt mplayer mpv
>     openshot openshot-qt peek phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc pulseeffects
>     python3-openshot qml-module-qtwebengine stremio vlc vlc-plugin-base
>     vlc-plugin-video-output vokoscreen wine wine-devel-amd64 wine-stable wine64
>     winetricks xsane
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 55 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   After this operation, 1075 MB disk space will be freed.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

Also  `libsnapd-glib1` will delete:

> `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas apturl-common calf-plugins gir1.2-goa-1.0
>     gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 gnome-software-common
>     gstreamer1.0-adapter-pulseeffects gstreamer1.0-autogain-pulseeffects
>     gstreamer1.0-convolver-pulseeffects gstreamer1.0-crystalizer-pulseeffects
>     libappstream-glib8 libzita-convolver3 mda-lv2 pavucontrol-qt-l10n rtkit
>     rubberband-ladspa zam-plugins
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
>   The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     apturl audio-recorder gir1.2-snapd-1 gnome-software indicator-sound
>     libcanberra-pulse libsnapd-glib1 paprefs pavucontrol-qt pulseaudio
>     pulseaudio-equalizer pulseaudio-module-gsettings pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
>     pulseeffects software-properties-gtk ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
>     ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-notifier
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
>   After this operation, 21,7 MB disk space will be freed.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

And finally `gir1.2-snapd-1` don't want:

> `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     apturl-common gir1.2-goa-1.0 gnome-software-common libappstream-glib8
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
>   The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     apturl gir1.2-snapd-1 gnome-software software-properties-gtk
>     ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
>     update-manager update-notifier
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
>   After this operation, 9013 kB disk space will be freed.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

**Snaps i love it !!!!**