# Do I need libsnapd-glib1 without snapd?

Tags: snap

Basically the title: I removed all snaps + snapd from Kubuntu 20.04, and now see 'libsnapd-glib1' asking to update...

Is it okay to just uninstall libsnapd-glib1 if I never plan on using snaps?

It's listed as optional, but I'm new to linux, and just want to be sure.

I saw [this post,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248542/snap-library-removing-gir1-2-snapd-1-libsnapd-glib1-libsnappy1v5-libsnappy1v) but I don't have gir1.2-snapd-1 installed, and there didn't seem to be any strong answers anyway.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what packages depend upon `libsnapd-glib1`:

```
$ apt rdepends libsnapd-glib1

libsnapd-glib1
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: gnome-software (>= 1.55)
  Depends: snapd-login-service (>= 0.9)
  Depends: gir1.2-snapd-1 (= 1.58-0ubuntu0.20.10.0)
  Depends: snapd-glib-tests (>= 1.57)
  Depends: libsnapd-qt1 (>= 1.57)
  Depends: pulseaudio (>= 1.49)
  Depends: libsnapd-glib-dev (= 1.58-0ubuntu0.20.10.0)
  Depends: gnome-initial-setup (>= 1.42)
  Depends: gnome-software-plugin-snap (>= 1.50)
  Depends: snapd-glib-tests (>= 1.57)
  Depends: libsnapd-qt1 (>= 1.57)
  Depends: libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (>= 1.26)
  Depends: pulseaudio (>= 1.49)
  Depends: libsnapd-glib-dev (= 1.57-0ubuntu4)
  Depends: gnome-control-center (>= 1.57)
  Depends: gnome-initial-setup (>= 1.42)
  Depends: gir1.2-snapd-1 (= 1.57-0ubuntu4)
  Depends: cups-daemon (>= 1.49)
```

Looks like a lot more than snapd uses that lib. Removal is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for that handy command!  I've only been using linux for a few months, so I sure appreciate your showing me how to get an answer myself as well as the actual answer! I don't have enough reputation to upvote (lol), but many thanks.